# Multiline Combobox Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox, multiline

I would like to build a multiline combobox in WPF. This would be similar to label control wherein the width of control will grow such that entire selected text is visible. The text displayed can go over next line if there is no enough space available on current line.

I tried few things around control template of combobox. But still no success.

Below is sample screenshot of how it should look like!

[image: Multiline Combobox]

Any pointers?

Thanks,
Sambhaji

Comment: create a control derived from textblock. On click show popup.

Comment: Hack yourself into the TextBox part of ComboBox and enable Multilines. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding setting the control template for this particular scenario would be a tedious job. I would have created a TextBlock and tried setting the event triggers which will open a container on mouse hover or click event.